# get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); Not Working for Certain Images

Tags: wordpress, image

I created a child theme. I added some images to the theme in an "images" directory. Four new images that I uploaded are not working.

I am calling them like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/banner-image.jpg">
```

Here's what's interesting: 1) It is only four images that don't work. 2) The image with with "http://www.url.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/imagename.jpg" doesn't work, if I remove "www" the path "http://url.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/imagename.jpg" works.

Right now I'm using literal paths in my theme. I want to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for better practice.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) function will return the **child's theme directory URI**.

Using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) to link a static image with its correct path in html:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
```

Using this hook function to add style in your child theme `function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css' );
```

}

Note: [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) instead of  [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Comment: get_template_directory_uri() was actually returning the parent directory for me. But the issue was really a caching issue, so, it's resolved. Thanks for the help!